# Add filters/refiners to CQWP webpart

Tags: sharepoint-online, filter, content-query-web-part, refiner, query-string

I am on SharePoint Online environment,

As a high level summary, we currently have pages that use a PageQueryString as a filter for a CQWP.  However, from the results that are displayed within the web part, we would like to have several filter buttons at the top of the page that further refine/filter the results that are currently displayed.

The ideal solution would be something similar to search results page where we add refiners to the page and drill down the results. I want to implement something similar on page but instead we want to filter down results to a specific location on a page that has CQWP web part results.

Are there any ways to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think of is to implement your CQWP filter and utilize more complex PageQueryString. You can put couple buttons in the page. When users click a button, it appends URL with different PageQueryString to mimic the "filter" functionality. If I recall correctly, you can only have up to 3 "filters" by doing this. Let me know what are the required filter options; I can help with more specific solution if needed.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. For example I have a post list. I want to filter the posts based on categories, so I am using Category = [PageQueryString : Category] filter in CQWP. Now I want to provide users to filter this category.aspx?category=1 page based on location, region and department. I want to provide something like a dropdown for users to choose from or something like refiners, where they select a specific location and all posts related to that category and location show up.

Comment: In that case you will use this format ?Category=1&Location=NY&Dept=HR. One thing to keep in mind is you can only have 3 filters in CQWP unless you export the webpart and play around with the XML. So I will use Target Audience or OOTB SP funcitons like _spPageContextInfo for your needs. Regarding the dropdown, you can just hard-coded the options and refresh the page whenever they make a selection. Is that makes sense to you?

Comment: hi YogaPanda. But i want to provide filters like Choice filter vs List view webpart, Where i can connect a filter to a webpart on the page and date refines dynamically.  Yes, i can hard code the options, but how will refine the data on the page (CQWP) with this dropdown? I mean how do i connect?